# Lua: table->hex id and hex id->table

Tags: lua, hex, lua-table

If I have a table, I can print it to get a unique hex ID.

```
> t = {}
> print(t)

table: 1554A170
```

Now say I had a string:

```
str = "table: 1554A170"
```

How can I access the `t` object?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? You can use a table to index another table. You don't need an hex id for that.

Comment: Thanks @lhf. I have decided to use a map to map between object and ID. You are right, I just needed a way to reference objects remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally `print()` will use `lua_topointer()` when printing table value.
Lua's manual tells next about `lua_topointer()`:

> There is no way to convert the pointer back to its original value.
>
> Typically this function is used only for debug information.